# Need a word for the inability to feel anger

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, terminology, vocabulary

I need a term for the inability to feel anger.  Features desired:

1. Single word
2. Prefer connotations of incapacity rather than benefit
3. Prefer reasonably clear specificity to anger
4. More clinical tone slightly preferred over less clinical

To illustrate what I mean by #2 and #3, I considered *serenity*, but that word has positive connotations rather than connoting incapacity, and implies the absence of emotions besides anger (fear, for example).

Comment: *Imperturbable* comes to mind.

Comment: @Autoresponder: Would also cover fear.  And the noun form is *imperturbability*, which is very clunky.

Comment: Apathy? Defeatism? Resignation? Passivity? Complacency?

Comment: Would [*alexithymia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexithymia) meet your criteria? Or is it too general (applies to all emotions)? It is definitely an incapacity and sounds clinical.

Comment: @JLG: Too general, and doesn't indicate an incapacity to feel, indicates an incapacity to verbalize.

Answer (score 4):

When one is unable to feel anger, and incapable of feeling any strong emotions, I would say that person is ***numb***.

You can be *numb* with grief; unable to shed tears and to express your sorrow.
You can be so ***stunned*** and be in ***shock*** that your whole mind and body is ***paralysed*** or ***frozen*** into a state of inactivity; this goes for emotions too.

In [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_detachment) I found this article:
***Emotional detachment***

Emotional detachment, in psychology, can mean two different things. In the first meaning, it refers to an "inability to connect" with others emotionally, as well as a means of dealing with anxiety by preventing certain situations that trigger it; it is often described as "**emotional numbing**" or dissociation, depersonalization or in its chronic form depersonalization disorder.

Answer (score 3):

What about "non-irascible"?

i·ras·ci·ble : having or showing a tendency to be easily angered

from lat "ira", anger,  wrath, rage

Comment: Pretty much the only answer so far that is specific to anger in any way. Good work. :)

Comment: thx ) - just found a different option, from ancient greek "orgilos - inclined to anger". Aristoteles seems to use the word "aorgesia - unirascibility". But it would count as a neologism nowadays and not be readily understandable. [link to google books](http://books.google.de/books?id=3JuePlN_03cC&pg=PA317&lpg=PA317&dq=aorg%C4%93sia&source=bl&ots=wJrzCPyQR_&sig=L3X-hn_rEJ1BUUVmfHJrP871Mwc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eSNgUs6SMeik4ASniYDwDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=aorg%C4%93sia&f=false)

Comment: ‘Inirascible’ seems like it would be a better negated form … but if Google is anything to go by, it's practically unknown in English, and quite rare in French.

Comment: Please. The opposite of irascible should be rascible. Let's make that happen!

Comment: I would argue that absence of a quality does not imply its opposite. Implying that someone doesn't have a quick temper doesn't mean that they are incapable of anger.

Comment: The antonym is 'unirascible'.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think there is a clinical term that is specific enough. Most will have strong psychiatric connotations. The only terms with clinical undertones that come to mind are ***inirritable***, *sedate* and [***non-choleric***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/non+choleric) or ***uncholeric***.

Here are a few alternative suggestions:

***unirascible***

*Wrathless*

*Unincensed*

***Unspleened***, ***spleenless***

*Angerless*

*avirulent*

***stomachless***, ***gall-less***

The bold ones are negative in connotation in my opinion, and mean *incapable of being roused to anger*.

Comment: Interesting that a several of these terms come from [humorism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humorism), an obsolete medical theory in which "yellow bile" (gall, cholera) was associated with anger and "black bile" with depression (spleen).

Answer (score 2):

You could also go for [*phlegmatic*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/phlegmatic):

> 1. having a stolid or unemotional disposition
> 2. not easily excited

I would tend to use it for someone who is excessively calm and, to me, it carries slightly negative connotations.

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities include *cold, passionless, heartless, affectless* or *of low affect*, *hyperrational, calculating*.

Comment: All of these are more general than I want.  None are specific to anger.

Comment: Seems like *affectless* is probably the closest, except that it is not specific to anger.

Answer (score 1):

**Passive-Dependent**

Passive is used as a clinical term, included in **[passive-dependent personality](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/passive-dependent+personality)** and **[passive-aggressive personality](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/passive-aggressive+personality)**.

Passive-dependent personality: a personality characterized by helplessness, indecisiveness, and a tendency to cling to and seek support from others.

Passive-aggressive personality: A personality disorder in which aggressive feelings are manifested in passive ways, especially through stubbornness, procrastination, and inefficiency so as to resist adequate social and occupational performance.

I would say that the passive-dependent person avoids or is unable to feel anger, while the passive-aggressive person feels anger, but does not exhibit it openly.

Other words that might have use beyond clinical are *passive*, *placid*, *sedate*, *staid*, and *tranquil*.

**Previous Answers:**

I'll throw these out, even though they described deliberate (conscious) attributes in addition to uncontrollable traits.

**[Good-natured](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-synonyms/good-natured)**: A good-natured person or animal is naturally friendly and does not get angry easily.

**[Tolerant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tolerant)**:  Inclined to tolerate the beliefs, practices, or traits of others; forbearing.

**[Forbearing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/forbearing)**: tolerant or patient in the face of provocation.

mild-mannered: (of a person) gentle and not given to *extremes of emotion*.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if you are talking about some sort of clinical dysfunction here. I suppose a psychotherapist would call it 'repression'.

Answer (score 0):

Docile - ready to accept control or instruction; submissive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are talking about. But a depressed person can neither feel real joy nor real anger. Numb was mentioned above already.

The thing with emotions is they as far as I know don't come in singles. Either you are passionate about something, then you can feel joy when you succeed or anger when you don't. If you are incapable then you are either depressed or detached which is more of a habit or reflexive defense mechanism. You are basically hiding yourself behind your rationale and become emotionally cold or detached.

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up using was a construction from Greek roots, *anagonia*.